# Plotting 2 datasets with different dates on the same plot in r

Tags: r, datetime

I have a Dataset_1 that only has some values some months, e.g.

```
Day Month   Year    Value
10  5   2003    12
17  5   2003    46
1   6   2003    23
16  6   2003    43
16  10  2003    23
26  10  2003    12
```

and Dataset_2 that has regular 1 hour values for the same time period e.g

```
Day Month   Year    Hour Value
10  5       2003    0:00 13
10  5       2003    1:00 12
(...)
26  10      2003    21:00 12
26  10      2003    22:00 12
```

Dataset_1 is used to evaluate Dataset_2. I would therefore like to plot the regular-interval-Dataset_2 against the not-so-regular-Dataset_1. Is there a way, probably using the date stamps that are in common, to plot all the timesteps of Dataset_2 but to get R to plot the points of Dataset_1 at the corresponding date of Dataset_2?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing you have to do is to declare your dates and time as indeed date and time objects:

```
Dataset_1$timestamp <- strptime(paste(Dataset_1$Day, Dataset_1$Month, 
                                Dataset_1$Year, sep="-"), format="%d-%m-%Y")
Dataset_2$timestamp <- strptime(paste(Dataset_2$Hour, Dataset_2$Day, 
                                Dataset_2$Month, Dataset_2$Year, sep="-"), 
                                format="%H:%M-%d-%m-%Y")
```

You can then plot your data normally without taking any specific precaution because `plot`will recognize they are date and time objects.

```
plot(Dataset_1$timestamp, Dataset_1$Value)
lines(Dataset_2$timestamp, Dataset_2$Value)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to get a simple 2d plot with date&time on the x coordinate (presumably with "value" on y), you'll have to express the date&time as real numbers first.

So you could define a function that maps date & time to a real number (e.g. unix time, or simply Hour + 24 * Day + ...), and plug in 0 for Hour in Dataset_1 (e.g. by doing Dataset_1$Hour <- 0, assuming your data are in a data frame).

Comment: Yes, it would be a 2D plot. I edited my question because I had not made it clear that I wanted all points from Dataset_2 plotted, not just the ones corresponding to Dataset_1. Given this change, would your suggestion still work? I'm afraid I don't understand how it would, could you expand a bit more? Thanks.

Comment: Actually @plannapus gave a much better answer, so forget what I said.